# (pytest, sqlalchemy, fastapi) Created object is not being deleted between test methods (rollback does not work)

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

I have problem with rollbacking between test methods of test class:

```
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import String, URL, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Mapped, mapped_column

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    first_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))
    last_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(255))


class UsersRepository:

    def __init__(self, session: AsyncSession):
        self._session = session

    async def create(self, **create_data):
        instance = User(**create_data)
        self._session.add(instance)

        return instance
    
    async def get(self):        
        return (await self._session.scalars(select(User))).one()

    async def delete(self, instance):
        self._session.delete(instance)

    async def commit(self):
        await self._session.commit()
        
    async def refresh(self, instance):
        await self._session.refresh(instance)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def engine():
    url = URL.create(
        drivername="drivername",
        host="host",
        port="port",
        username="username",
        password="password",
        database="database",
    )
    engine_ = create_async_engine(url)
    yield engine_
    await engine_.dispose()


@pytest.fixture
async def session(engine):
    session_ = AsyncSession(engine)
    session_.begin_nested()
    yield session_
    await session_.rollback()  # does not work
    await session_.close()


@pytest.fixture
async def users_repository(session):
    return UsersRepository(session)


class TestMe:

    async def test_created(self, users_repository):
        user = await users_repository.create(first_name="John", last_name="Snow")
        await users_repository.commit()
        await users_repository.refresh(user)
        
        # after test method ran I expect create user will be rollbacked
        # to make sure the created object is deleted I delete it manually:
        # await users_repository.delete(user)
        # await users_repository.commit()
        
    async def test_not_created(self, users_repository):
        await users_repository.get()  
        
        # here the object returned that was created in test_created
        # but I expected it was rollbacked
```

There are methods `test_created` and `test_not_created`. During `test_created` method execution an object being created. At the end in fixture `session` I expect the object being rallbacked. But this does not happen. How to delete it automatically?

It is also ok if `engine` fixture has scope equal to `function`. Why this happens?

Comment: You're calling commit: `await users_repository.commit()`, which calls `await self._session.commit()` - why do you expect a commit to not happen?

Comment: @MatsLindh, how can't I commit in business logic?)

Comment: You can - but you're asking why you can't roll back - there is nothing to roll back, since _you have committed the changes_. If you want to do a rollback, you can't commit the transaction first - rollback means "abort the current transaction". Since you've committed the transaction, there is nothing to roll back.

Comment: I see that you're using `begin_nested` to have nested transactions, but this requires rdbms support - so in that case it'll depend on what you're running as the underlying db engine - see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_transaction.html#joining-a-session-into-an-external-transaction-such-as-for-test-suites for notes - you'll have to create the transaction on the connection first at least from what I can tell